# Table adapter not updating to database

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a form system that takes in the staff personal data (with the purpose to create an account) the data is correctly taken and entered into the dataset (**dataSet2**).The line below was what I believed was the correct set of code to update the database (**Database1**).The data correctly enters the dataset without an issue but I do not see any data entered into the database at all, there are no error codes output or provided. All help is appreciated.

```
namespace COMP_SCI_2
{
    public partial class staff_createacc : Form
    {
           
        public staff_createacc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            string[]DATAINPUT = { IDBOX.Text ,TITLEBOX.Text,FORENAMEBOX.Text,SURNAMEBOX.Text,DATEBOX.Text,STREETBOX.Text,TOWNBOX.Text,POSTCODEBOX.Text,PHONEBOX.Text,EMAILBOX.Text,POSITIONBOX.Text,PASSWORDBOX.Text };


        dataSet2.STAFF.Rows.Add (DATAINPUT);
        this.sTAFFTableAdapter.Update(this.dataSet2);
        }
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key/auto-incrementing column?

Comment: @KarenPayne I'm not familiar with the term auto incrementing column but that table does have a primary key (STAFF_ID)

Comment: When you call `Update`, there are only three possible outcomes. Either an exception is thrown, it returns zero or it returns a non-zero value. Which is it in your case? Most likely it is the last option, which means that everything is working as it should and you're just not looking for the changes properly. That is far more common than you might think.

Comment: See the [following](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) regarding auto incrementing primary key

Comment: @user18387401 During the program operation and after pressing the save button, I looked inside the database and saw that a row of data was added but after i exit the program and open it again the row had disappeared again? (what I had expected to happen was that when I opened the program again the table on that form would fill with the saved information from the database)

Comment: *"I ... saw that a row of data was added"*. Then you lied in your question. If you saw a record added then you know the code worked, so the actual question you want answered is why that record disappeared, so you should have provided that information and asked that question.

Comment: Sorry, Im just very confused about how it would show up and disappear later on.

Comment: But if you don't tell us that that's what happened and that's what you're confused about, we can't help your confusion. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: I'm away to more classes, when I'm back ill update my question and try to be a little more succinct, and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local data files work a specific way in .NET projects. When you add a data file to your project, e.g. MDF or ACCDB, that is a source file. It is part of your project, not part of your application. When you build your project, the output is written to a folder. That output consists of the compiled EXE and, amongst other things, it can include a copy of your source database.

By default, a new copy of the database is created every time a new EXE is compiled. That means that, if you run your project and modify the database, then change the code and run the project again, your changes will be overwritten by a new copy of the source database. If you run the project again without making any code changes, you'll see that your data changes have persisted.

In the Solution Explorer, your data file has a *Copy to Output Directory* property and it is set to *Copy Always* by default. That means that the source database is copied over the working database on every build. If you change that to *Copy if Newer* then the working database will only be overwritten when you make changes to the source database, e.g. change the schema or the initial data. That way, any changes you make while testing will persist across builds and you can just manually delete the working file when you want to force a refresh.

For the record, the reason that it's done this way is so that your source database doesn't get polluted with your test data. If that were allowed to happen, you'd have to clean it up before deploying. The way it's implemented, your simply change to Release, click Build and your Release output folder will be populated with a nice clean database, ready to be deployed to your users.

Answer (score 1):

If a row was added than you ran the app again to display data and nothing shows. This sound like the database resides in the app folder.

The default for the database property `Copy to Output Directory` is `Copy always` which means each time the app runs it overwrites the database. You need to change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`

See the following Microsoft TechNet [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx)

[image]

**EDIT**
Did not see the other post with the same information when posting this.